# Is it dangerous to stand or squat on a toilet seat?

Tags: safety, toilets

I got a recent junk mail with the photo attached

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk5Ex.png (Warning: graphic images of the alleged injuries)

About the danger in pooping standing position and its result. This claim is for real?

Comment: The first picture is of someone using a toilet that's designed for squatting, and can be seen at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flush_toilet#Cultural_variations

Comment: It is said that by squatting over the toilet allows the muscle around the anus to relax and lets the poo come out easier, so the Japanese have got it right for many centuries with there squat toilets. The picture of the women with the large cut to her leg appears to have sustained that injury from a propeller because i have seen an injury that was actually caused by a propeller and it looks a lot like that one.

Comment: The injury is most likely real. Here (GRAPHIC! http://www.flickr.com/photos/30953130@N08/4175393263/) there are 2 other images of the same injury. The question is whether the toilet claim is real.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3080/101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of links on wikipedia regarding this topic ...

> Furthermore, injuries are frequently sustained by people who stand on
>   toilet seats to reach a height, and slip

[Toilet-related injuries and deaths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet-related_injuries_and_deaths)

Comment: For what value of "frequently"? Does this imply it's statistically more likely than an injury from a plane crash or shark attack? Or just in comparison to not standing on the toilet?

Comment: @hippietrail I'm not firm in english, my understanding would be most reports concern people "standing on the toilet" vs. usual uasge.